# How to test razor view rendering

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, razor, razor-pages

I would like to test the rendering of my cshtml with mocked data. So I want to pass some data to a mocked database InMemory and checking if all element who should be there is displaying correctly.

This is my frontend code:

```
page "{page?}"
@model as_quebec.Pages.Public.TextsModel
@{
    Pager pager = new Pager();

    int pageNo = 0;

    if (Model.Pager != null)
    {
        pager = Model.Pager;
        pageNo = pager.CurrentPage;
    }
}
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using as_quebec.Models;
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager

<div class="container col-xxl-8 px-4 py-5">
    <div class="row align-items-center g-5 py-5">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
            <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold lh-1 mb-3">
                Textes
            </h1>
            <p class="lead">Amitiés Spirituelles</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1604849/pexels-photo-1604849.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1600" class="d-block mx-lg-auto img-fluid" width="400" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<partial name="~/Pages/Shared/Texts/_Pager.cshtml" model="@pager" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h4 class="mb-5 display-3">Textes des AS</h4>

            <div class="mb-3">
                @if (Model.Tags != null && Model.Tags.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var tag in Model.Tags)
                    {
                        @if (tag.TagManagement.RestrictedToMembers)
                        {
                            @if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
                            {
                                <a class="text-decoration-none" href="/tags/@tag.Name.Replace(" ", "+")">
                                    <span class="badge bg-dark">@tag.Name</span>
                                </a>
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <a class="text-decoration-none" href="/tags/@tag.Name.Replace(" ", "+")">
                                <span class="badge bg-dark">@tag.Name</span>
                            </a>
                        }
                    }
                }
            </div>

            @if (Model.TextPosts != null && Model.TextPosts.Any())
            {
                @foreach (var text in Model.TextPosts)
                {
                    @if (text.Tag.TagManagement.RestrictedToMembers)
                    {
                        @if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
                        {
                            <div class="mb-5 bg-light box-shadow">
                                <img src="@text.FeaturedImageUrl" alt="@text.Heading" class="mb-2 d-block img-fluid" />
                                <div class="px-4 py-4">
                                    <h2 class="mb-2">@text.Heading</h2>
                                    <p>
                                        Auteur: @text.Author
                                        <br />
                                        Date de publication: @text.PublishedDate
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="mb-2">@text.PageTitle</p>
                                    <a href="/text/@text.Id" class="btn btn-dark">Lire</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div class="mb-5 bg-light box-shadow">
                            <img src="@text.FeaturedImageUrl" alt="@text.Heading" class="mb-2 d-block img-fluid" />
                            <div class="px-4 py-4">
                                <h2 class="mb-2">@text.Heading</h2>
                                <p>
                                    Auteur: @text.Author
                                    <br />
                                    Date de publication: @text.PublishedDate
                                </p>
                                <p class="mb-2">@text.PageTitle</p>
                                <a href="/text/@text.Id" class="btn btn-dark">Lire</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<partial name="~/Pages/Shared/Texts/_Pager.cshtml" model="@pager" />
```

The element that I would like to test here is that all TextPosts is displaying on the page and not the ones who are restricted to member.

This is my backend code:

```
public class TextsModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ITextPostRepository _textPostRepository;
        private readonly ITagRepository _tagRepository;
        public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

        public List<TextPost> TextPosts { get; set; }
        public Pager Pager { get; set; }

        public TextsModel(ITextPostRepository textPostRepository, ITagRepository tagRepository)
        {
            _textPostRepository = textPostRepository;
            _tagRepository = tagRepository;
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
        {
            TextPosts = (await _textPostRepository.GetAllAsync())
                .Where(x => !x.Tag.TagManagement.IsMeeting)
                .ToList();
            Tags = (await _tagRepository.GetAllAsync())
                .Where(x => !x.TagManagement.IsMeeting)
                .ToList();

            ViewData["Title"] = "Textes";

            if (int.TryParse(Request.Query["page"], out int page))
            {
                InitializePage(page);
            }
            else
            {
                InitializePage(1);
            }

            return Page();
        }

        private void InitializePage(int page)
        {
            const int pageSize = 5;
            if (page < 1)
            {
                page = 1;
            }

            int recsCount = TextPosts.Count();

            var pager = new Pager(recsCount, page, pageSize);

            int recSkip = (page - 1) * pageSize;

            TextPosts = TextPosts.Skip(recSkip).Take(pager.PageSize).ToList();

            Pager = pager;
        }
    }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Use Selenium or Playwright or similar browser automation tools for testing what is rendered.

Comment: Ok, I then see that tests with the rendering with Selenium are integration tests, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.